# error in asp net core 3 the partial view was not found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
InvalidOperationException: The partial view '_navbar' was not found. 
The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/_navbar.cshtml
/Views/Shared/_navbar.cshtml
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialCoreAsync(string partialViewName, object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData, TextWriter writer)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2rw5.jpg)

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_navbar")

    <p>@ViewBag.Greeting @ViewBag.UserName ,Necesiniz?</p>
    <p>Umid edirem memnunsuzx</p>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: the `Shared` directory should be inside the `views` directory in your case it is outside of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> InvalidOperationException: The partial view '_navbar' was not found.

From [this doc about "Partial view discovery"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1#partial-view-discovery), you would find:

*When a partial view is referenced by name without a file extension, the following locations are searched in the stated order:*

MVC

1. /Areas/<Area-Name>/Views/
2. /Areas/<Area-Name>/Views/Shared
3. /Views/Shared
4. /Pages/Shared

To reference `_navbar` partial view, you can try these approaches:

1. As @ABDEL-RHMAN mentioned, you can try to move it to `/Views/Shared` folder.
2. Besides, if you do not want to change your folder structure, to make it work, you can try `@await Html.PartialAsync("../../shared/_navbar")`.